# How to save ACLs of a directory tree and then restore it on another server, as SID mapping is not guaranteed?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, access-control-list, icacls, sid

ICACLS can save ACL of a tree with the command below, where `a_dir_root` is the root of this tree:

```
icacls a_dir_root\ /save AclFile /T /C /Q
```

Of course, groups are identified as SIDs. I want to restore them on another server, which has the same group set by name, but their mapped SID aren't the same as the source server.

Is there a simple and elegant way, or should I plan writing a script for this task, ie some lines to replace into the ACL file all SIDs by the mapped names? (an automated version of a [brute force replacement](https://serverfault.com/a/312532/316845))

---

Once I used a Bash script running on Cygwin, but of course it got hit by [BLODA](https://cygwin.com/faq/faq.html#faq.using.fixing-fork-failures). I'm asking before starting coding